# Is it possible for me to use RAM sold to me as “Model for Mac” in my Lenovo T420?

Tags: memory, upgrade

Can you tell me if it is safe to try a RAM Upgrade that I bought regarding correct parameters for my Lenovo T420 computer:

> Crucial 8GB PC3-10600S DDR3-1333MHZ 1.5v 204Pin SO-DIMM Laptop Memory RAM.

But purchased without enough information from seller regarding “Model for Mac”

The manufacturer specs denies in its website, the model CT8G3S160BM to fit Lenovo.

Any comment from you will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The "model for Mac" is probably ECC memory. It's an extra feature that, if supported by CPU and motherboard, lets the computer correct some random bit flips. ECC memory is used in servers and Apple hardware, but not very common outside of it, because it's more expensive and memory errors aren't that common to be a serious risk in consumer world.

You can safely test if it works. Worst case scenario is the computer won't boot and removing this memory module will fix it.

Comment: Gronostaj,Many   thanks for your answer.I received a Crucial 8GB RAM for MAC,(crucial 8GB PC3-10600S DDR3-1333MHZ 1.5v 204Pin SO-DIMM  MAC Laptop Memory RAM )  bought through ebay.de ,that runs perfectly well upgrading my old T420, now to 16 GB.All of the Lenovo test (that took almost 95 minutes) were completed fully OK.I saved 50% off  from standard price ,I thought ,and went ahead.When I read the word "MAC" on the stick label ,I had my doubts and came to you.Many thanks for your time